# Cannot add property to mongoose document with findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My `express` app tries to record the login time of the user using `Mongoose's` `findOneAndUpdate`.

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureFlash: true,
    failureRedirect: '/'
}), async(req, res, next) => {
    // if we're at this point in the code, the user has already logged in successfully.
    console.log("successful login")
    // save login time to database
    const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.body.username }, { loginTime: Date.now() }, { new: true });
    console.log(result);
    return res.redirect('/battle');
})
```

The user document does not start out with a login time property. I'm expecting this code to insert that property for me.

The actual result is, the console shows the user document being printed out, but without any added login time property. How can I fix this so a login time property is inserted into the document? Is the only way to do it by defining a login time property in the original mongoose schema? And if so, doesn't that nullify the supposed advantage of `NoSQL` vs `SQL` in that it's supposed to allow new unexpected property types into your collections and documents?

Comment: You can check what is the value in `req.body.username` (that will verify if a corresponding document exists).

Comment: That is not the problem. The document already exists, I can see it in the database and the console.log(result) prints the full document out. The problem is that no loginTime property was added to the document using findOneAndUpdate.

Comment: Check if the program is connecting to the right database and the collection?

Comment: It is connected to the right database and collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer for anyone who might come across the same problem. It is not at all possible to add a property to a Mongoose collection if it is not already defined in the Schema. So to fix it I added the property in the Schema.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can add a new property that isn't defined in the schema, without modifying the schema. You need to set the flag `strict` to false to enable this mode. See document [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict).

The code below demonstrates what I said, feel free to runs it:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// connect to database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });

// define the schema 
const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String

    // this flag indicate that the shema we defined is not fixed, 
    // document in database can have some fields that are not defined in the schema
    // which is very likely
}, { strict: false });

// compile schema to model
const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

test();
async function test() {

    // empty the database
    await Kitten.deleteMany({});

    // test data
    const dataObject = { name: "Kitty 1" };
    const firstKitty = new Kitten(dataObject);

    // save in database
    await firstKitty.save();

    // find the kitty from database
    const firstKittyDocument = await Kitten.findOne({ name: "Kitty 1" });
    console.log("Mongoose document", firstKittyDocument);

    // modify the kitty, add new property doesn't exist in the schema
    const firstKittyDocumentModified = await Kitten.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: firstKittyDocument._id },
        { $set: { age: 1 } },
        { new: true }
    );
    console.log("Mongoose document updated", firstKittyDocumentModified);

    // note : when we log the attribute that isn't in the schema, it is undefined :)
    console.log("Age ", firstKittyDocumentModified.age); // undefined
    console.log("Name", firstKittyDocumentModified.name); // defined

    // for that, use .toObject() method to convert Mongoose document to javascript object
    const firstKittyPOJO = firstKittyDocumentModified.toObject();
    console.log("Age ", firstKittyPOJO.age); // defined
    console.log("Name", firstKittyPOJO.name); // defined

}
```

The output:

```
Mongoose document { _id: 60d1fd0ac3b22b4e3c69d4f2, name: 'Kitty 1', __v: 0 }
Mongoose document updated { _id: 60d1fd0ac3b22b4e3c69d4f2, name: 'Kitty 1', __v: 0, age: 1 }
Age  undefined
Name Kitty 1
Age  1
Name Kitty 1
```